# JQuery / JavaScript to get value from table after clicking on row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery or JavaScript, how can I get a value of a `<td>` in a `<table>` which looks like the following -

```
<table class="MyTable">
   <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td class="MyClass">5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sally</td>
      <td class="MyClass">9</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If a user clicks on "John's row", the value captured should be "5".
If a user clicks on "Sally's row", the value captured should be "9".

I have the row captured in the following JQuery -

```
$('table.myTable tbody tr').on('click', function () {

   //I want to capture <td class="MyClass"> value here, something like this -
   var myValue = $("this.td#MyClass").val() //DOESN'T WORK!

}
```

I'm not sure what my `$(this).` statement should look like, I've tried several things like - `$("this.td#MyClass").val()`, but it returns 'undefined'. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myValue = $(this).find('.MyClass').text();
```

Use `.val()` when you're retrieving values from HTML controls, like `<select>` elements for instance. Here you're getting text so use `.text()`